# populating a dictionary with list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am trying to populate a dictionary `d`, with keys from a list`names` 
e.g.

```
names=['a','v']
[d.update({str(n+'__k'):[1,2]} for n in names)]
```

However,

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

How to get `d={'a__k':[1,2],'v__k':[1,2]}`?
Why is this an error?

Comment: I do not really understand why you want to update a dictionary through list comprehension instead of a simple loop?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary comprehension?

Comment: Also, you have a typo: You never close the parentheses after update, so it is interpreted as a generator expression.

Comment: Hunt: the brackets do not match.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem you were right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern versions of Python you can create a dictionary with a dictionary comprehension:

```
{x: '%s__k' % x for x in names}
```

Note that I prefer to use the string % operator rather than concatenation.  it's slightly more efficient, but also easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by separating the two operations of updating and dict creation by using a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
{n+'__k':[1,2] for n in names}
```

Should work just fine. If you need to update `d`, then you can do:

```
d.update({n+'__k':[1,2] for n in names})
```